# Replacing a line by the one just before

Tags: python

My issue is simple but I'm really out of ideas;
My raw data looks like:

```
xxx,1593,7
\N
yyy,1094,4
ddd,1015,0,2
zzz,1576,5
\N
aaa,1037,6
```

I run the following code:

```
 list_data = data.split('\n')
    for line in  list_data:
        if len(line.split(',')) >= 3 :
            flag = True
            print( line.split(',')[1])
        else : 
            print(line)
```

The output I get:

```
1593
\N
1094
1015
1576
\N
1037
```

I need to replace each '\N' by the number of the line just before. So my output should look like :

```
1593
1593
1094
1015
1576
1576
1037
```

If you have any Idea please help.
Thank you!

Comment: You could do this with `pandas`... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your program here, but a simple edit in your script will give you the result that you are looking for.

I have not changed most of your code except for two lines.

```
list_data = data.split('\n')
for line in  list_data:
    if len(line.split(',')) >= 3 :
        flag = True
        print( line.split(',')[1])

        # I store the "normal" lines' year here, so if the next line is
        # not "normal" I print this prev

        prev = line.split(',')[1]    

    else: 

        # if len is less than 3, print the previous year
        print(prev)
```

Will give you,

```
1593
1593
1094
1015
1576
1576
1037
```

Comment: It is not printed in the `if` AND `else`. If the `len` is less than 3, then it goes into the `else` and prints the previous rows' year - which is what the OP's desired output looks like

Comment: Thank you the code is working. (I feel dumb not to think about that)

Comment: If you find the answers posted here useful or provides solution to your question, feel free to up-vote or mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    num = ''
    for line in data:
        line = line.split(',')
        if len(line) > 1:
            print(line[1])
            num = line[1]
        else:
            print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the logic for preparing your final list and printing/displaying. This would allow you to use some of the list comprehension methods as well.

```
#incoming data
data = "xxx,1593,7\n\N\nyyy,1094,4\nddd,1015,0,2\nzzz,1576,5\n\N\naaa,1037,6"

#function for processing
def getData(x):
    if len(x.split(',')) >= 3:
        return x.split(',')[1]
    else:
        return x

#create initial list from incoming data
List = [getData(x) for x in data.split("\n")]

#print and do replacements
for i, item in enumerate(List):
    if item == "\\N":
        print(List[i-1])
    else:
        print(item)
```

You may need to check for "\N" as the first element as well.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thank you! It's okey to return in this case an empty string